# How to use the combination of multiple columns as hue in a python plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I have a pandas data frame with the columns [Country, Region, Temperature, Time] and I want to plot the time on the X-Axis and the temperature on the Y-Axis.
When I now want to distinguish between the Country I can simply say

```
hue="Country"
```

If I want to distinguish between the Region I can simply say

```
hue="Region"
```

But is it possible to distinguish between the combination of Region and Country? So setting the hue to something like

```
hue="Country, Region"
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

So far I have tried this and it is what I want but I do not think this is an elegant solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data_frame = pd.read_pickle('data.pkl')
data_frame["Hue"] = data_frame["Country"] + data_frame["Region"]

ax = sns.lineplot(data = data_frame, x='Time', y="Temperature", hue = "Hue")
```

Comment: Please do share what you have attempted so far.

Comment: What kind of plot are you working with?

Comment: I edit the originial Question to include more information